# Why does my dishwasher make a singing / whistling sound

Tags: dishwasher, noise

I own an LG dishwasher about 2 years old (model [LDF8874ST](http://www.lg.com/us/dishwashers/lg-LDF8874ST-integrated-dishwasher)).

I have used this dishwasher regularly and have been really impressed with how quiet it runs. So it was very obvious when in the last couple of weeks it started to make a high-pitched noise when running (almost like whistling or singing). Can anyone please advise on possible causes?

Answer (score 1):

Sure sounds like a worn-out bushing / bearing pack. The squeal will get worse with time and become a screech. If it is a worn out drive belt the issue is just as complex.
 I have looked at LG's site for this product and it seems that this is definitely NOT a DIY job. LG offers tech support and possibly repair locations.
 Unless you are an expert at replacing bearing packs / belts and have a lot of specialized tools, I would send it out for repair, or you might have the option of an in-house repair.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But would bearings really fail less than 2 years in? If this is the case, I'll have to check if it is still under warranty.

Comment: Absolutely check the warranty status first. It could save a lot of money if under warranty. This is something you would want under warranty, because this is NOT a DIY project. As for the premature bearing or belt failure, it sounds like the manufacture uses low quality parts. They are supposed to last just past the warranty date, then fail. The reason is that high-performance bearings or belts can cost 10 times as much, cutting deeply into their profit margin. It is dirty pool, but most all manufactures do that. Only military, and space industries have the funding to buy the 'good stuff'.

Answer (score 0):

amazingly and they dont want you to know but where the shaft of the motor goes thru the bottom thru a rubber gromet....add a drop of white lithium grease ( a couple of bucks for a tube of it ) on the shaft where the gromet would touch the shaft and....WOW... fixed..... the high pitched squealing is metal on rubber... a little lubricant and its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with buildup of residue (soap scum, scale, lime, etc.) in the recirculation system.  I contacted LG about this on numerous occasions and they advised running white vinegar or a commercial cleaner through the system.  I tried both vinegar and commercial cleaners numerous times, with no positive results.  Then, quite by accident, we switched dishwashing detergent from Cascade liquid to **Cascade Platinum pods with Dawn**.  After about a month using the pods, the dishwasher is as quiet as it was when it was new, with absolutely no whistling.